# How do define a command that takes parameters like \verb?

Tags: macros

I would like to define a newcommand that takes one required parameter, but instead of passing it in using `{...}` as normal, to use a different parameter delineator like the `\verb` command does (e.g., `\mycmd|args|`).  Trying to do this with a normal `\newcommand` definition seems to behave strangely.

Comment: See also [Can you interpret macro parameters as verbatim? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256983/can-you-interpret-macro-parameters-as-verbatim) if you **want** catcode sanitization.

Answer (score 12):

If you do not want catcode sanitization:

```
\newcommand\myverb[1]%
    {\def\domyverb##1#1{ the argument was `##1'}%
     \domyverb}
```

and then use it as follows.

```
\myverb|test|

\myverb+test+

\myverb!test!
```

Answer (score 5):

It mostly depends on what you want to do. If all you need is to use the argument "as is", then

```
\def\mycmd|#1|{...#1...}
```

will do. This doesn't check whether `\mycmd` is defined; if you need the check, then use

```
\makeatletter
\@ifdefinable\mycmd{%
  \def\mycmd|#1|{...#1...}%
}
\makeatother
```

If you need this to do "verbatim" things, the definition must be quite more complicated.

Comment: what about defining a command whose argument can be placed between a pair of arbitrary symbols? How is `\verb` defined so that `\verb|spleen|`, `\verb+spleen+`, etc. work?